# Async/Await Sending and Receiving network Data

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, asynchronous, async-await

I am attempting to wrap up both the sending and receiving of data to a server using the async/await pattern. What I have created is an event driven socket framework that fires events whenever data is received from the server. However, I am having trouble trying to figure out how to await the thread, after the send, so that I do not return until the data from the server returns.

In the past I used a manual reset event to achieve this...

```
byte[] returnData;

public byte[] SendData(byte[] data){
    socket.Send(data, 0, data.Length);
    manualResetEvent.Wait();
    return returnData;
}

public void OnDataReceived(byte[] serverData){
    returnData = serverData;
    manualResetEvent.Set();
}
```

This method simply pauses the caller thread until the reset event is triggered. This is no good as I want the async/await pattern so that the calling thread is free to do other work while waiting for the data from the server.

What I have now is....

```
byte[] returnData;

public async Task<byte[]> SendData(byte[] data){
    await socket.SendAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
    //await something that frees up this thread to do other work
    return returnData;
}

public void OnDataReceived(byte[] serverData){
    returnData = serverData;
    //do something that pushes SendData back into the active context
}
```

I think I am doing somethign wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Where's the code that fires the event that's handled by `OnDataReceived`?

Answer (score -1):

I have found a suitable solution.

Instead of using a [`ManualResetEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), I can use what is called a [`TaskCompletionSource<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This gives me the functionality I need to allow the thread pool to wait for some state change.